# Absolute Positioning - Bottom issue

Tags: html, css, position

I have an element: `#home-img-text-container2` that while in the viewport of under 640px I position it `absolute` and give it a `bottom: 0;` placement. My issue is that the `#home-img-text-container2` goes past the main container/image `#home-main-img`.

I have set the container like this:

```
#home-img-text-container1, #home-img-text-container2 {
    position: absolute;
}
#home-img-text-container2 {
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
}
#home-img-text-description, #home-img-text-description2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px;  
    padding: 20px 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

I don't understand why it won't position right at the very bottom of the image, rather than under it.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Again, this is in the media query 640px.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24sck8rs/1/)

Comment: Is this you are trying to achieve? [https://jsfiddle.net/24sck8rs/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/24sck8rs/2/)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks!

Comment: @Rohit I'm not sure what happened to your fiddle? It changed for some reason. Feel free to leave an answer if you can get the fiddle back to how it was.

Comment: I don't see any change? It is working as you want in question. Let me know what is the issue?

Comment: @Rohit I can't even tell what you changed?

Comment: Give me your fiddle link, I will check. I think this is updated [https://jsfiddle.net/24sck8rs/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/24sck8rs/2/)